# Determine if estimator is unbiased

Tags: statistics, regression-analysis, parameter-estimation

I need to find out if the following estimator for a regression with no intercept (ie. $Y_i = \beta X_i + \epsilon_i$) is unbiased.

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum x_i^2y_i}{\sum x_i^2}$$

I'm given $\bar{x},\bar{y} $ both = 0. I know I need to find if $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}] = \beta $, but I keep getting stuck. Any help would be really appreciated!

Update: I have changed the summation signs to be more clear, sorry this is my first time using this site and I'm still working on getting the code correct.

Comment: What do the parentheses around $\ x_i^2\ $ and $\ y_i\ $ signify in the numerator of the fraction inside the sum?

Comment: I fixed the brackets, both $x_i^2 $ and $y_i $ are in the numerator

Comment: For OLS yes, but this is what the question asked :/

Comment: Now I don't understand why you have $\ x_i^2\ $ in both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction.  Why don't these cancel each other to leave you with just $\ \hat{\beta}=\sum y_i\ $?

Comment: Sorry I realized the summation signs were incorrect, perhaps now it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(\hat{\beta}\big)&= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i^2\big(\beta X_i+\epsilon_i\big)}{\sum_iX_i^2}\right)\\
&= \beta\,\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i^3}{\sum_iX_i^2}\right)+ \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_i\epsilon_i\left(\frac{X_i^2}{\sum_j X_j^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\beta\,\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i^3}{\sum_iX_i^2}\right)+ \sum_i\mathbb{E}\big(\epsilon_i\big) \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X_i^2}{\sum_j X_j^2}\right)\\
&= \beta\,\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i^3}{\sum_iX_i^2}\right)
\end{align}
Thus $\ \frac{\sum_i x_i^2y_i}{\sum_ix_i^2}\ $ will be an unbiassed estimator of $\ \beta\ $ if and only if $\ \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i^3}{\sum_iX_i^2}\right)=1\ $, which will not usually be the case.  Note, however, exactly the same technique will show $\ \frac{\sum_i x_i^2y_i}{\sum_ix_i^3}\ $ to be an unbiassed estimator.  Are you sure you have the right exponent in the denominator of your putative estimator?

Comment: For this particular class we are given a bunch of different estimators like this and asked to show if they are unbiased or not. Thank you so much!

Comment: If the exponents in your estimator are as you've given them, then the calculation I've given is actually overkill. A very simple dimensional analysis will tell you that $\hat{\beta}$ cannot be unbiassed in general.  If $Y_i$ is measured in metres, for instance, and $X_i$ in seconds, then $\beta$ must have units of $\text{ms}^{-1}$, but $\hat{\beta}$ has units of just m. If you were simply to change the units of measurement of $X_i$ to *minutes* instead, then $\beta$ should have to increase by a factor of $60$, but the numerical value of $\hat{\beta}$ would not change.